# GeoIP module (mod_geoip2) and Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, geoip

I have installed GeoIP mod via http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/ and have made sure the permissions are correct for www-data to read the database. We are just needing to block a directory from Great Britain due to the nature of the medical industry. When I enable it, even I am blocked from it from the US as well as GB (I would assume everywhere is). Since this is directory blocking, after adding the proper module configuration to the apache2.conf, all I would need to add is the .htaccess file to the proper directory:

```
<Location /geoip-enabled>
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GB BlockCountry
    Deny from env=BlockCountry
</Location>
```

Is there anything else that should be included in the .htaccess? When it's active, it generates a 500 Internal Server Error and the logs reflect

> [core:alert] [pid 23183] [client x.x.x.x:65490] /www/prime/non-uk/.htaccess: Location not allowed here from every connection.

Comment: So `<Location /geoip-enabled>` is a path on your server that is something like `http://example.com/geoip-enabled`? Do you actually have `GeoIPEnable On` and `GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat` set? The [examples here are fairly clear cut](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) so wondering what your fuller setup is.

Comment: As per the instructions from the link you posted (as well as the one I posted in my opening statement), I set the variables on.

<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable Off
GeoIPEnableUTF8 On
GeoIPOutput Env
GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
</IfModule>